# Escaping characters in JavaScript using their ASCII codes

Tags: javascript, escaping, bookmarklet

I am creating a bookmarklet and I have to avoid using double quotes ( " ) because I have to include the bookmarklet inside a HTML page and it's inside a string that uses double quotes:

```
<a href="javascript:...">
```

In some places I have to use the code `replace(/".*/, '');`

In sed, I can escape double quotes using `\x22` (22 is the ASCII hex code for double quotes)

Is it possible to do something similar in JavaScript like `replace(/\x22.*/, '');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you would use quotes in any HTML attribute's value.

example

```
<img src="..." alt="A picture of Bob &quote;Wild Man&quot; Johnson">
```

so for you

```
<a href="javascript:replace(/&quot;.*/, '');">
```

Comment: No offense, but "also worked" is a bit of an understatement. This is the *right* answer. This is how you write HTML. (Your code is being written into HTML.) The suggestion from theram will mark the programmer as a bit clueless. Yes, his suggestion kind of works OK for your very limited case, but as soon as you start needing more quotes for other purposes, it becomes ridiculous. Look at my answer history; I know a thing or two about bookmarklets.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the other syntax for making a RegExp and use `String.fromCharCode`

Here's an example:

```
'"hello"'.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(34), 'g'), '-quotes-')

-->

'-quotes-hello-quotes-'
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! I used `var x = x.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(34) + '.*'), '');` and it works nice

Comment: Perfetto! Perfetto!